# this sql query not work and show error #1111Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT reg.name,
       SUM(donatecheck.donate)
FROM   reg,
       donatecheck
WHERE  reg.email = donatecheck.email
       AND SUM(donatecheck.donate) > 4000
GROUP  BY reg.name;
```

there is two table `reg` and `donatecheck`,i want to fetch name ,`totaldonation` from database for each person and its not repeated..
`donatecheck` table `attributes==email`,`catagory`,`donation` and `reg` `table==name,email`

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to fix formatting at best I could do. Perhaps you should take some time to review those changes. While waiting for answers you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to know what you should do when someone answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

the aggregate functions like sum can not be used in WHERE, they have to be used in group by, using the 'HAVING' keyword

```
SELECT reg.name,
       SUM(donatecheck.donate)
FROM   reg
       JOIN donatecheck
         ON reg.email = donatecheck.email
GROUP  BY reg.name
HAVING SUM(donatecheck.donate) > 4000;
```